# First-grader problem in arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, education

I found this problem in a text book on arithmetic for first graders (7 y.o.) of the former USSR<sup>*</sup> . The problem comes from the section that covers single-digit addition and subtraction. Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: Image from the book]

This is the entire problem: there is no textual description accompanying it, and of course no answer at the back of the book. Other problems in the section are of the `1 + 6 =` and `8 - 7 =` kind, so this should be an elementary problem as well. However, I cannot figure out what is being asked here: I do not remember this notation, because we used different text books.

Can anybody figure out what is being asked by this assignment?

---

<sup>*</sup>  A.S.Pchyolko, G.B.Polyak "Arithmetic" Fifth edition. Text book for the first grade of elementary school. Moscow, Printing house of the Department of Education, 1959

Comment: Perhaps the question is saying to add $6$ to each number on the outside, so the answer would be $(9, 10, 8)$ (starting from the top and rotating clockwise) for the first one. See [this](http://www.softschools.com/math/addition/addition_circle_worksheets/), which is similar. (Basically what @BrianM.Scott said, except 14 seconds later ;)

Comment: ^ makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the student is to produce three numbers by adding the number in the centre of the circle to each of the three around it. (Of course by adding $-6$ I mean subtracting $6$, since I assume that the students had not yet been introduced to negative numbers.) I note that the indicated subtractions are all possible in the non-negative integers, a fact that can be viewed as some small evidence in favor of the interpretation.

Comment: +1 I think that's it! The additions stay within the 0..10 range as well, which is the case for problems 1..199 in that book! Thank you very much, I'll accept as soon as the system lets me click the check mark.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Notice that one of the numbers on the circle doesn't work each time.  I think the student is supposed to mark or circle the one that is incorrect on each circle.  (Although I don't know what you're supposed to do with the last circle...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: What do you mean by *doesn’t work*?

Comment: On the first circle, two of the numbers added to the number inside the circle produce numbers on the second circle, but there is one that does not  ( 3 + 6  and  4 + 6 are represented on the second circle, but  2 + 6  is not).  Similarly for the next two circles (all right, but what of the  -7  in the fourth circle?).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: Ingenious, but almost certainly a coincidence. Moreover, it leaves the last circle unaccounted for.

Comment: Yes, that is so.  I am assuming that since the problem is stated without words, there is something simple a student is being asked to do to the diagram.  But maybe they _are_ just supposed to write down the sums they calculate...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is to produce the number in the middle of the circle using the numbers on the outside. So $(3 \cdot 4)/2=6, 10-7-9=-6, (3 \cdot 2)+1=7, (8-9) \cdot 7=-7$.

Comment: Unlikely in the context given.

Answer (score -1):

I notice the first 2 numbers +6 and -6 can be produced by rearranging the given numbers with + and - signs:

2+4 = 6

10 - 9 - 7 = -6

But the last 2 aren't too clear